# Clicking on a Field with Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize-ruby

I am trying to use mechanize to click what appears to be a button, however, when I look at the CSS it seems to be a form field.

```
<input type="submit" name="tbe_cws_submit" value="Search" style="
padding:2px;
color:#FFFFFF;
border-left: 2px solid #11A9F7;
border-bottom:1px solid #333333;
border-right:1px solid #333333;
border-top:2px solid #11A9F7;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family:Verdana;" tabindex="13">
```

When looking at the page from irb, using mechanize, here is what I see.

```
:028 > page.forms[0].fields[4]
 => [text:0xddbe6c type: text name: ctl00$quickSearch$txtQuickSearch value: Search]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try submitting the enclosing form, thats what clicking the submit button would do.

`page.forms[0].submit`